# My Bitcoin transaction is lost

Tags: transactions

When I enter the deposit address of where I sent my bitcoin, the Blockchain says that the transaction is "Spent" What does this mean? It's been like this for 3-days now. Please help!

Comment: Hello, welcome to Bitcoin.SE! We'll need more info to help you (name of wallet / service you sent coins to, the transaction ID, etc), but it sounds like you've sent some bitcoin to a service and your account hasn't been properly credited yet (despite the tx being confirmed). If this is the case, then this is a customer service issue that you'll need to resolve with the service in question.

Answer (score 2):

> **the Blockchain says that the transaction is "Spent" What does this mean?**

It means that the outputs of the transaction have been used as inputs in a further transaction.

Which, in simpler terms, means that the recipient has subsequently spent the received money.

If you were the recipient, have a conventional (non-custodial) wallet and didn't knowingly spend the money it probably means you have lost control of your wallet as a result of hacking or social engineering or some other hostile act by a third party. For example where an online "friend" helped set up your wallet or where you clicked an "update" notice in an old Electrum wallet.